# Hibernate parameterized query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following method:

```
public List<Book> searchGroups(String title, String subtitle, String author) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM book GROUP BY title, subtitle, author;").addEntity(Book.class);
    return query.list();
}
```

I'd like to include the title, subtitle and author as search parameters but only when they're not null. How can I do that? For example if subtitle and author are null, I'd only like to search by author.

Answer (score 0):

Use [a Criteria query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria), which is precisely designed to construct queries in a dynamic way:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Book.class, "book");
if (title != null) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("book.title", title);
}
if (subtitle != null) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("book.subtitle", subtitle);
}
if (author != null) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("book.author", author);
}
List<Book> books = c.list();
```

PS: your SQL query doesn't make sense. `group by` is supposed to be used with aggregate functions.

EDIT: since you in fact want to aggregate rows which have the same author, title and subtitle together, you can't return a `List<Book>`, and must add projections to your query:

```
c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(
    Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("book.title"))
        .add(Projections.property("book.subtitle"))
        .add(Projections.property("book.author"))));
List<Object[]> result = c.list();
```

Comment: I know about criteria but I need to only get distinct results. For example I have three books: two have the same title, subtitle, author and the third has the same title and subtitle but a different author. I need the first two books to only show up as one entry.

Comment: Then you can't return a `List<Book>`, since a Book has an ID that makes it different from all the other books. Add a distinct projection and three property projections to your query. EDIT coming.